# Can't return exact data, issue with group by

Tags: sql

## I need help working though the following problem:

#### List the last person to change to each department, and which department they changed to.

Table: dept_start_times

```
|   person_id   |    department     |        start_time       |
|       1       |    Auto           |   2018-01-01 08:20:00   |
|       1       |    Garden         |   2018-01-01 12:20:00   |
|       1       |    Electronics    |   2018-01-01 14:20:00   |
|       2       |    Garden         |   2018-01-01 08:20:00   |
|       2       |    Electronics    |   2018-01-01 09:20:00   |
|       2       |    Auto           |   2018-01-01 16:20:00   |
|       3       |    Auto           |   2018-01-01 08:20:00   |
|       3       |    Garden         |   2018-01-01 12:20:00   |
|       3       |    Auto           |   2018-01-01 14:20:00   |
|       4       |    Auto           |   2018-01-01 08:20:00   |
|       4       |    Electronics    |   2018-01-01 12:20:00   |
|       4       |    Garden         |   2018-01-01 14:20:00   |
```

I tried the following which is incorrect, but this is as close as I can get to the solution. Missing the person_id column.  If I include it, it includes every person_id and department which I don't want.

```
SELECT department, MAX(start_time)
FROM dept_start_times
GROUP BY 1
```

```
department     |    max
Electronics    |    2018-01-01T14:20:00.000Z
Garden         |    2018-01-01T14:20:00.000Z
Auto           |    2018-01-01T16:20:00.000Z
```

Comment: So for each department you need to print the latest joiner, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a correlated subquery or `row_numer()`:

```
select dst.*
from dept_start_times dst
where dst.start_time = (select max(dst2.start_time)
                        from dept_start_times dst2
                        where dst2.department = dst.department
                       );
```

Comment: That did it, thank you for the guidance @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 1):

Join what you have back to `dept_start_times`:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dept_start_times as d
  JOIN (SELECT department, MAX(start_time) as first_start_time
          FROM dept_start_times
         GROUP BY department) as x
    ON x.department = d.department
   AND x.first_start_time = d.start_time
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. You could use what you have as an `uncorrelated` subquery to filter the result set

```
select person_id, department, start_time
from dept_start_times 
where (department, start_time) in (select department, max(start_time)
                                   from dept_start_times 
                                   group by department)
```